# Helmholtz free energy minimization using Lagrange

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, variational-principle

can you please help me with that one:

Minimize free energy for a liquid crystal:

$F = \int (K_{11} (div(n))^2 + K_{22} (n*rot(n) + q)^2 + K_{33} (n*rot(n))^2 ) dV$

in the case $n = cos(\alpha)*e_z + sin(\alpha)*e_\phi$ in cylindrical coordinates. $\alpha$ is only dependent of $r$. Goal is to get second order differential equation $\alpha = \alpha(r)$ with the Euler Lagrange law.